# Access forbidden on a website even if the directory doesn't change

Tags: javascript, php, apache, web

So I'm doing a pentest on a website . There is a news section and basically in the url the news pages go from 1-600
When I try to change the page from the url for example change 559 to 558 it says access forbidden even tho I can open the 558 page from inside the website with a. Link. And when I try to change it back to 559 it says access forbidden again . I'm not really sure what system is in action or where is it configured to be like this . Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a referrer check, or cookie set in the site normally, or access permissions following a login or certain action. With a pen test all you can do is flag up potential vulnerabilities. The owner of the site will then be able to tell you if it makes sense, or whether it's just their permissions model in action, or whether you've found a hole that should not be there. It's harder to test whether the permissions are overly restrictive though, without knowledge of the business rules of the site.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a referrer check, you could test if the page is loading when you add the `Referer` header when calling it.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote on this? Since it's just a wild guess?